Call the “remove_doubles” operator with a popup window of operator parameters
I don't understand how to call the “remove_doubles” operator so that it opens with a popup window of operator parameters. Is it possible in principle when calling an operator from a custom class (custom operator)?
Here are implementation variants that are guaranteed to work, but do not call windows with operator parameters.
import bpy
import bmesh

class KEY_MergeByDistance(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.key_mergebydistance"
    bl_label = "KEY_MergeByDistance"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        # VARIANT 1
        win = bpy.context.window_manager.windows[0]
        screen = win.screen
        area = next(area for area in screen.areas if area.type == "VIEW_3D")
        override = {
        "window": win,
        "screen": screen,
        "area": area
        }
        bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(override)
        
        # VARIANT 2
        obj = bpy.context.active_object
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=False)
        bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles('INVOKE_DEFAULT', threshold=0.0001)
        
        # VARIANT 3
        obj = bpy.context.active_object
        bm = bmesh.new()
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
        bmesh.ops.remove_doubles(bm, verts=bm.verts, dist=0.001)
        bm.to_mesh(obj.data)
        obj.data.update()
        bm.clear()
        
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(KEY_MergeByDistance)
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(KEY_MergeByDistance)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


You use a call to  context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog() with a draw method added to your operator. This will make the op call a dialog before you press OK to run it.
import bpy
from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C

import bpy
import bmesh

class KEY_MergeByDistance(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.key_mergebydistance"
    bl_label = "KEY_MergeByDistance"
    
    distance: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Distance", default=.001)
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object.type == "MESH"
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.activate_init = True
        row.prop(self, "distance")
        
    
    def execute(self, context):
        # VARIANT 3
        # don't use bpy.context, just use the context that is passed into the operator
        obj = context.active_object
        bm = bmesh.new()
        bm.from_mesh(obj.data)
        bmesh.ops.remove_doubles(bm, verts=bm.verts, dist=self.distance)
        bm.to_mesh(obj.data)
        obj.data.update()
        bm.clear()
        
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(KEY_MergeByDistance)
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(KEY_MergeByDistance)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


Thanks for the advice. If I understood you correctly - there is no possibility to call the original popup window of the operator. We can only add our own popup window and pass to it the values of some operator's argument. Or is there a way ?

I'm not absolutely sure but yeah I think this is the case. I don't know why you would want to do that anyways if you only want to calll the remove doubles operator. In that case why not just call that operator itself?
